# Skip a mutation if one variable is undefined

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I have a mutation which is triggered on onClick.
This mutation accept one NOT optional variable.
This variable comes from a query.

Since the query might fail, the variable might be undefined and typescript complains.
Thus my question: how can I skip the mutation if the variable is undefined?

```
 const { data: myQueryData } = useQuery(GET_MY_QUERY_DATA, {
    variables: {
      firstVariable: 100
    }
  })

  const myVariable = myQueryData?.getMyQueryData <-- This is "number" | "undefined"

  const [updateMutation] = useMutation(
    UPDATE_STUFF
  )

   updateMutation({
     variables: {
       myVariable <-- This, as before, can be "number" | "undefined"
       BUT it cannot be undefined since it is NOT optional
     }
   })
```

Comment: `if(myVariable) updateMutation`

Comment: Thanks, I did that. I would like to know if there is another way. What if I do not need 1 variable but 10? Should I use a lot of `&&` to verify if they are present?

Comment: `const myVariable = myQueryData ? myQueryData.getMyQueryData : 0;`

Comment: ...`if(myQueryData)` can be good enough (as condition) for many derived from query result [possibly failed] data

Comment: The issue with this approach `myQueryData ? myQueryData.getMyQueryData : 0;` is that I do not want it to be `0` if it fails. I want the mutation not to run

Comment: 0 can be blocking value ... use some general blocking flag (`useState(false)`) cleared on `onCompleted` - block mutation until query data available, covers many derived data, too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by React. Because we can't conditionally call hooks we always have to invoke them in the same order.

`useQuery` executes the Query immediately. For this reason a `skip` flag was included to control if it should run or not ([Query API](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#skip)).

```
useQuery(Foo, { skip: true })
```

`useMutation` doesn't have that option ([Mutation API](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/)). Mutations work slightly differently in that their execution is differed until the callback is invoked. But thankfully the callback isn't a hook and can be conditionally called. So the solution is to conditionally call it.

```
const [runMutation] = useMutation(MyMutation)
if (...) {
  await runMutation()
}
```

```
const myVariable = myQueryData?.getMyQueryData
if (myVariable) {
  updateMutation({
    variables: {
      myVariable
    }
  })
}
```

---

I ran into this problem as I wanted to generate graphql mutations for a range of IDs.

```
const MyMutation = gql`
  mutation MyMutation {
    ${inputIds.map((id) => `cancelEntity(id: "${id}")`).join('\n')}
  }
`
```

But if the input array is empty this forms a bad `DocumentNode`.

So I tried to conditionally generate the mutation returning an empty DocumentNode.

Failed to parse empty input

```
const Mutation = gql``
```

Failed to parse comments

```
const Mutation = gql`
    # noop
`
```

Failed to parse empty mutation: Unexpected EOF

```
const Mutation = gql`
  mutation Foo {
    # noop
  }
`
```

I tried to generate a noop DocumentNode to pass to the `useMutation`. But this failed as it recognises it's not a Query, Mutation or Subscription.

```
const Mutation: DocumentNode = {
  kind: 'Document',
  definitions: [
    {
      kind: 'FragmentDefinition',
      name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'noop' },
      typeCondition: {
        kind: 'NamedType',
        name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'noop' },
      },
      selectionSet: { kind: 'SelectionSet', selections: [] },
    },
  ],
}
```

I wish I was able to generate a valid empty mutation. Because we are packaging this mutation in its own hook and returning the mutation callback. This means many components could leverage this hook and invoke the mutation. All of which are now responsible for conditional invoking the mutation.

```
const { cancelEntity } = useCancelEntity(inputIds)
if (inputIds && inputIds.length > 1) {
  await cancelEntity()
}
```

We could package the mutations into a single mutation and call it many times.

```
await Promise.all([cancelEntity('1'), cancelEntity('2')])
```

This creates cleaner code but forces us to make many network requests.